# How to create and read a JSON file in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I first created my JSON class, here is the code:

```
Public Class Fich

    <JsonProperty("title")>
    Public Property Title As String

    <JsonProperty("name")>
    Public Property Name As String

    <JsonProperty("charge")>
    Public Property Charge As String

    <JsonProperty("institute")>
    Public Property Institute As String

    <JsonProperty("celebration")>
    Public Property Celebration As String

End class


Public Class Prenommer

    <JsonProperty("fiches")>
    Public Property Fiches As Fich()

End Class
```

Then my data string:

```
Dim rawJson As String = "{""Title"":""TextBox2.Text"",""Name"":""TextBox1.Text"",""Charge"":""TextBox4.Text"",""Institute"":""TextBox15.Text"",""Celebration"":""TextBox5.Text""}"
```

On this string, I would like it to take into account the TextBox text of my main sheet. For the moment I can't do it, I don't see what I can replace the quadruple quotes that surround them!

And above all, if I can understand the method to achieve this, how to create and read the JSON file with the data from the TextBoxs!

Claude

Comment: I wouldn´t write the json string at all. Use your objects and set their properties, e.g. in the TextChanged event handler of the TextBoxes. When finished use an JSON converter e.g. [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) to serialize the objects to an JSON String, e.g. `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Prenommer)`

Comment: Thanks Alex B. I'll take a closer look at the page you pointed out to me. Claude.